# directory problem when starting apache for django (wsgi)

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

after having created a small local web application with django, I want to be able to access it remotely by hosting it with apache and nginx and gunicorn. However I have an error on the directory entered in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

I get the following error when starting apache:

```
"Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code"
```

Recording after in detail, I saw this error:

```
"apache2: Syntax error on line 235 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf : Expected </Directory\xc2\xa0/home/pi/Desktop/ecole> but saw </Directory>"
```

My additions in the apache2 conf files:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/Desktop/ecole/école/école/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/pi/Desktop/ school/
<Directory /home/pi/Desktop/school>
<Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

I don't understand the problem, thank you for coming back.

Comment: You have a space in the `WSGIPythonPath` line, it should be `:`.

Comment: Yes this is that, thank you for your feedback